# Looker Studio: Tracking users from multiple sources over multiple months

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

I am working on building out reporting in Looker Studio for our website. I would like to have a trendline chart with the top source/mediums tracked over multiple months (ideally with a "cumulative" trendline at the top).

What I have built out is a chart with Month as the dimension and Total Users as the Metric. My thought is that the easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a custom field with the logic of "Total Users when Session Source = google". After that, I would build out custom fields for all potential sources. I attempted building this out with LookML, but it's not as intuitive a language as I was hoping. Is this the easiest way to go about solving this, or am I missing something?